# Product Page Smarty Variable in Prestashop

Tags: variables, module, smarty, prestashop, editing

I'm a pretty amateur to PHP and CSS, but I'm trying to edit a Prestashop 'Request a Quote' module I got for a website. Basically, I'm trying to work out if there's a Smarty variable I can use to grab the url of the product page the 'Request a Quote' button is pressed on. There seems to be some variables (I'm assuming it's based on Smarty...?) which grab the product name and description. Here's a sample of the code, showing the data the form grabs;

```
<p class="required textarea" id="demande">
            <textarea name="demande" style="width:95%;" rows="12"  {if isset($devis) && ($devis->total_devis !=0 || $devis->reponse)} readonly{/if} >{if isset($desc_prod) && $desc_prod != null}{$desc_prod|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}{elseif isset($smarty.post.demande)}{$smarty.post.demande}{elseif isset($devis)}{$devis->demande|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}{/if}</textarea>
```

And here's some of the $desc_prod code;

```
$desc_prod = null;
            if($id_prod = Tools::getValue('id_product'))
            {
                $prod = new Product($id_prod);
                $desc_prod = $prod->name[$this->context->language->id].' : '.$prod->description_short[$this->context->language->id];
            }
```

Am I on the right track here? Again, very amateur, self taught largely. Is there a quick and easy way for me to set up this form to grab the product's url when the button is pressed?

Thanks guys! :)

Comment: you have to call the method getProductLink of Link class,

http://blog.gofenice.com/prestashop/global-smarty-variables-used-in-prestashop/

Answer (score 0):

Use the class "Link"

```
$link=new Link;
$productUrl=$link->getProductLink($idProduct);
```